# execute ftp with white space in path

Tags: powershell, ftp

The following PowerShell script runs an ftp command but returns an error as it cannot get find the absolute source path (which includes white space and does take the complete path as "File One” and “Destination One".

Output:

```
/usr/bin/lftp -c \"mirror --only-missing --verbose sftp://jason@10.1.1.1:/e:/Files/File One e:/Files/Destination One/File One\"

Access failed: No such file (e:/Files/File)
```

The values of each variables are hardcoded and cannot be changed for a reason. In that case, what are the changes required in the $ftppath or $ftpcmd to include these white spaces in the source and dest, so it can return the ftpcmd correctly. Could someone please help?

Script:

```
# these values are hardcoded and cannot be modified

$root = "/e:/Files"
$source = "File One"
$dest = "e:/Files/Destination One/File One"
$user = "jason"
$server = "10.1.1.1"

# ftp command
$ftppath = "sftp://$user" + '@' + $server + ':' + $root + '/'  + $source + ' ' + $dest
$ftpcmd = '/usr/bin/lftp -c \"mirror --only-missing  --verbose ' + "$ftppath"+'\"'
$ftpcmd
Invoke-Expression -command $ftpcmd
```

Comment: will you try one of theses and give us a feedback?
    * `$dest = "e:/Files/Destination One/File\ One"`
    * `$dest = "e:/Files/Destination One/File%20One"`

Comment: Yes, adding the escape character "e:/Files/Destination One/File\ One" works. But in my case, i can't update the dest variable because it is hardcoded for a reason.

Comment: so if i get you right, the $ftppath or $ftpcmd are the only variables you can change ?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but I think that [posh-ssh](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/07/03/posh-ssh-open-source-ssh-powershell-module/)  is a smarter way to do that .

Comment: @SoufianeMghanen, correct

Comment: $ftppath = "sftp://$user" + '@' + $server + ':' + $root + '/'  + $source.replace(" ","\ ")
 + ' ' + $dest.Replace(" ","\ ") 
how about this ?

Comment: that works! Thanks @SoufianeMghanen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i guess you can simply use it like thi:

```
# these values are hardcoded and cannot be modified

$root = "/e:/Files"
$source = "File One"
$dest = "e:/Files/Destination One/File One"
$user = "jason"
$server = "10.1.1.1"

# ftp command
$ftppath = "sftp://$user" + '@' + $server + ':' + $root + '/'  + $source + ' ' + $dest
$ftpcmd = '/usr/bin/lftp -c \"mirror --only-missing  --verbose ' + "$ftppath"+'\"'
$ftpcmd
Invoke-Expression -command $ftpcmd.replace(" ", "\ ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```shell

## ftp command

$ftppath = "sftp://$user" + '@' + $server + ':' + $root + '/'  + $source + ' ' + $dest

```

replace by this,use quote wrap $dest

```shell

## ftp command

$ftppath = "sftp://$user" + '@' + $server + ':' + $root + '/'  + $source + ' ' + "${dest}"

```